# Time signature inconsistent

Tags: time-signatures, lilypond, tuplet, engraving

I'm trying to write the first measure of the Moonlight in Lilypond
[image]

> From my very basic knowledge the first measure is 4 x 3 x 1/8 = 3/2 long, but the special symbol (alla breve) seams to be a 2/2.
>   What I'm missing?

The lower part (bass), on the other side, is fine.

If someone knows Lilypond, here is my start

```
\version "2.19.82"

musicA = {
  \key e \major
  \time 2/2
  \overrideTimeSignatureSettings 3/2 3/8 #'(1 1 1 1) #'()
  \relative c' { g8 fis c' e g,8 c e g,8 c e g,8 c e }
}

musicB = {
  \clef bass
  \key e \major
  \time 2/2
  c1
}

\new PianoStaff {
  <<
    \context Staff = "up" {
      \accidentalStyle default
      \musicA
    }
    \context Staff = "down" {
      \accidentalStyle default
      \musicB
    }
  >>
}
```

All the notes are wrong, but I think/hope to know enough to correct it myself.

Comment: triplets, dude!  :-)

Comment: It appears you're new to sheet music.  I would recommend learning a bunch of stuff about notation and reading sheet music before trying to generate your own in LilyPond .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The notes in the upper staff are tuplets. As an aid towards your eventual goal, here is some sample code to create what you're looking for:

```
\version "2.19.82"

musicA = \relative c' {
  \key cis \minor
  \time 2/2
  \omit TupletNumber
  \override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = ##f
  \tuplet 3/2 4 { gis8_\markup { \italic { sempre \dynamic pp e senza sordino } }
                  cis e gis,[ cis e] gis, cis e gis,[ cis e] } |
}

musicB = \relative c, {
  \clef bass
  \key cis \minor
  \time 2/2
  <cis cis'>1 |
}

\new PianoStaff {
  <<
    \context Staff = "up" {
      \accidentalStyle default
      \musicA
    }
    \context Staff = "down" {
      \accidentalStyle default
      \musicB
    }
  >>
}
```

This compiles:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The notes on the treble clef are triplets. That's all.

Comment: do you mean a triplet of 1/8 is 1/4 long instead of 3/8?

Comment: If I'm not misinterpreting what you just wrote, yes, that's the way it is. If you need to check anything with some established version, [here](http://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/1/19/IMSLP51726-PMLP01458-Beethoven_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_16_No_137_Op_27_No_2.pdf) is the scan from a Leipzig publisher, which is identical to every version I've ever seen of this piece. Just to know: are you familiar with triplets? If not, you may want to look that up.

Comment: Music notation always leaves stuff out, stuff that (in that period) the composer deliberately left up to the performer to decide.  But sometimes, like this, it abbreviates in a way that annoys computer programmers and language lawyers but is completely reasonable to the everyday performer.

Answer (score 4):

Triplet eighths are 2/3 the duration of a real eighth, so if you don't want to put every note in a triplet you can also give all notes a scaled duration. So your music would be

\relative c' { gis8*2/3 cis e gis, cis e     % etc

Remember to remove any other explicit durations so that implicit durations prevail from the first note here.